# AWS Glue Python Shell script timing out

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-vpc, pygresql

I am trying to connect to and read an on-premise data source using an AWS Glue Python Shell job. I am using Pygresql (which comes bundled on Glue) and Pandas. Everything works locally.

But when I push this job up to Glue, the database connections all timeout. Why is this happening? Do I need to do something magic with VPCs?

Comment: What is the error that you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to create a Glue connection with your VPC settings and attach it to the Glue job.

Answer (score 0):

Note that pygresql SQL query doesn't work in python shell. Recommended is postgresql